How to prove expended fields whose base has same cardinal are isomorphic?
I would like to prove that for field $F_1,F_2$ if they :

have isomorphic sub-field $F'$
$F_1,F_2$ is the vector space over $F'$, and their bases, doneta $B_1,B_2$, has the same cardinal

Then $F_1,F_2$ are isomorphism.
It is clear that for any $a\in F_1$ we can linearly express it as $a=\sum_{i=1}^nk_ie_i$ where $k_i\in F'$ and $e_i\in B_1$
Since they have the same cardinal, then there is a bijection $\psi:B_1\to B_2$, then we can define function $\phi:F_1\to F_2$ that satisfy $\phi(a)=\phi(\sum_{i=1}^nk_ie_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nk_i\psi(e_i)$
The hard part for me is to prove that $\phi(a\cdot b)=\phi(a)\times\phi(b)$ where $\cdot$ is the multiplication in $F_1$ and $\times$ is the multiplication in $F_2$
One of the key thing is for $e_i\cdot e_j$ where $\{e_i,e_j\}\subset B_1$, it is clear that this can also be linearly expressed as $e_i\cdot e_j=\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\cdot e_k$
To satisfy the multiplication, we need to prove that $\psi(e_i)\times\psi(e_j)=\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\times\psi(e_k)$ and I would like to ask if I can prove this? Is there a possibility that $\psi(e_i)\times\psi(e_j)\ne\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\times\psi(e_k)$ ??

If $F_1$ are the algebraic numbers (over $\mathbb{Q}$) and $F_2=\mathbb{Q}(x)$ the rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then they both have $\mathbb{Q}$ as subfield, and countable bases over $\mathbb{Q}$. After all both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are countable. They are not isomorphic, since $F_2$ contains a transcendental element $x$, but $F_1$ does not.

@ameg Thanks a lot. I want to prove this is mainly due to the theorem saying that if two algebraic closed fields has same characteristic and cardinal, they are isomorphic from my text book. Is that true?? and if you can, may I see the prove

@ameg Why not make your comment into an answer?

When you ask who’s do you mean the English equivalent of whose?

(just to add another example of a slightly different flavor to ameg's, consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$; each of these has dimension $2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, but they are not isomorphic (why not?))
